# How to extra top n lines from a multi line string in bash (sed/awk/??)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Given a number of jstack threaddumps, I need to extra the top x lines from each thread's stack trace.

I am able to extra each thread stack trace but once I have the multi-line string, how to extra the top x lines?

For example, for each of the thread traces below, the output needs to be

```
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
```

for the 1st trace if x = 4.

```
"kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1" Id=279 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:686)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:408)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-4" Id=660 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:686)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:408)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"kafcli-poller-18" Id=322 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:686)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:408)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:261)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1171)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-20" Id=1746 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:686)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:408)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"kafcli-poller-3" Id=287 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:686)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:408)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:261)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:233)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1171)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-12" Id=1200 RUNNABLE (in native)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.select(Selector.java:686)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:408)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:239)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:163)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. It's very difficult to help you debug code that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below snippet

```
awk '/in native/ {for(i=1; i<=4; i++) {getline; print}}' temp.log
```

**temp.log** file contains the sample log in your question

Comment: That's great, you just need to lose the cat. `awk ...... temp.log` is better without the subshell of the pipe

Comment: minor change (added a variable). `awk '/in native/ {for(i=1; i<=$ENDLINE; i++) {getline; print}}'  temp.log`.How can update the end in the for loop to say up to $ENDLINE since the thread stack could be less than $ENDLINE in total size, as delineated by a newline?

Comment: @user2943574 I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for but if you want all lines expect the first (one containing **in native**) and blank line, then `awk '!/in native|^$/ {print}' temp.log` should do the trick. If this is not what you are looking for, then update your question with expected output.

Answer (score 1):

With `grep` gonna be much simpler

```
grep -A4 RUNNABLE logfile
```